# How to use one object every time on form submit?

Tags: php, sockets, object, yii, scope

I am working with sockets in PHP and Yii. I have a form with following fields:

```
ip
port
message
```

Action is called containing following socket programming code and packet is sent successfully when I submit the form.

```
$socket = socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp') );
socket_connect( $socket, $address, $port );      
$status = socket_sendto( $socket, $message, $len, 0, $address, $port );

if( $status !== FALSE ) {                        
   $next = '';                        
   while( $next = socket_read( $socket, 1000 ) ) {                     
       $response .= $next;
       if( strpos( $response, "\n" ) !== false )
           break;
   }                 
} else {
   $response = "Failed";
}

socket_close( $socket );
```

The problem is that whenever I submit a form with different **packet/message**, a new **connection/socket** is created and then packet/message is sent. I want to create socket only once and then send message/packet using **form** with same socket. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible directly -- at least given my understanding of the question -- because each time the form is submitted a separate PHP process accepts it and sends the message. Since it's a separate process, it needs its own socket.

What you could do is break up the PHP code in to parts:

1. The frontend, which will accept the form submission and
2. The backend, which will send the socket message

With this arrangement you can keep the backend running (and keeping its one and only connection open) while the frontend is spawned anew each time a form is submitted. Of course, this means that you also need to arrange for the frontend to communicate with the backend (the backend need not even be written in PHP).